# Function inside a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to execute my function inside a query like this

```
$re = $bddp->prepare("SELECT * FROM `shop`, `hours` WHERE isOpen('`hours`.`day1`') = true";
$re->execute();
```

`hours`.`day1` is a varchar with opening hours of monday like this "10:00-14:00"

Function `isOpen` test if its open or not and return `true` or `false`

The question is who i can send `hours.day1` like a variable into `isOpen` function in **WHERE isOpen('`hours`.`day1`')** ?

Its not possible to use PDO prepare or execute for this ?

Comment: Ideally... you should store open and closing hours, as well as the day, in separate columns (that will mean your table will need to be normalised), then you can simply check if a time and day provided fall within the range.

Comment: Yes its the best solution but many shop have alternate hours like "10:00-14:00 - 16:00-20:00 - 22:00-00:00"

Comment: To start with, is the function a PHP function or a user defined MySQL function?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: If it is a user defined MySQL function, then check how you are åassing the values. Currently, you're passing the literal string `hours.day1` since you have it inside single quotes. If you remove the single quotes, it's still wrong, since it then is trying to pass the column `day1` from the table `hours` (try a comma instead of a dot).

Comment: No the problem it is a PHP function not Mysql function. I think i will change all my table hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SQL query you can use only MySQL native functions, [stored functions/procedures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) and [User-Defined Functions (UDF)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html).

I think that you would not have a problem if the table structure was right (start-end times were in the separate columns). Then you would able to achieve your goal only with a few conditions in the WHERE part.

If the data amount (rows count) is not big, then you can just select all rows and done the validation in the PHP side.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh... really, I forgot it, thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes its good solution but the number of rows is over 10 000. I will change my table structure like you say.